# Regular expression on Yahoo! pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I'm fooling around with [Yahoo! pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) and I'm hitting a wall with some regular expression. Now I'm familiar with regular expressions from Perl but the rules just seem to be different in Yahoo! pipes.

[image: Screenshot of my pipe]

What I'm doing is fetching a page and trying to turn it into a feed, my regex for stripping out the link from the HTML works fine but the title which I want to be what was in *<i>* tags  just outputs the original text.

Sample text that matches in Perl and on this [online regexp tester](http://www.quanetic.com/regex.php):

> <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" HREF="http://changed.to/protect/the-guilty.html"><i>"Fee Fi Fo Fun" (English Man)</i></a> (See also this other site <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Nada</a>) Some other text here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RegEx for the title:

```
(?i).*?<i>([^<]*).*               [ ] g  [x] s  [ ] m  [ ] i
```

RegEx for the link:

```
(?i).*?href="([^"]*).*            [ ] g  [x] s  [ ] m  [ ] i
```

Somehow the case-insensitive checkbox seems broken. Luckily you can substitute with `(?i)`, which works nicely.

Here is a nice web2.0-ish tool to test regular expressions with: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). But for some reason it's still beta. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to watch out for with YP is do not trust the debug screen, it has a small quirk of hiding some tags from view that can cause no end of confusion when attempting regexing. To expose any hidden html replace '<' with something like '#'