# regex for all characters on yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo-pipes

I have an apparently simple regex query for pipes - I need to truncate each item from it's (`<img>`) tag onwards.  I thought a loop with string regex of `<img[.]*` replaced by blank field would have taken care of it but to no avail.

Obviously I'm missing something basic here - can someone point it out?

The item as it stands goes along something like this:

```
sample text title 
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com"><img border="0" src="http://example.com/image.png" alt="Yes" width="20" height="23"/></a> 
<a.... (a bunch of irrelevant hyperlinks I don't need)...
```

Essentially I only want the title text and hyperlink that's why I'm chopping the rest off

Going one better because all I'm really doing here is making the item string more manageable by cutting it down before further manipulation - anyone know if it's possible to extract a href from a certain link in the page (in this case the 1st one) using Regex in Yahoo Pipes?  I've seen the regex answer to [this SO q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360492/regular-expression-on-yahoo-pipes) but I'm not sure how to use it to map a url to an item attribute in a Pipes module?

Comment: ... is the question missing some details?

Comment: rutherford, we need more background information; can you please post some data?

Comment: The only thing I would guess from the info you gave is that `[.]` looks for a character class consisting of only the dot character. You might have meant: `.*` instead of `[.]*`.

Comment: hmm must be way off the mark, I thought . was the wildcard reference.  Will update

Comment: Yep, `.` is the wildcard for any character, except for inside `[]` which defines a set of characters to look for.

Comment: you regexp shoud work, especially if you remove the square brackets

Comment: I removed the square brackets and only the img tag was removed, not the subsequent links - does . take into account linebreaks?

Comment: Not by default, you have to set multi-line matching (in Perl thats the `$*` flag, in Java you add the flag to the `Pattern` compile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the line returns with a RegEx Pipe and replace the pattern [\r\n] with null text on the content or description field to make it a single line of text, then you can use the .* wildcard which will run to the end of the line.

http://www.yemkay.com/2008/06/30/common-problems-faced-in-yahoo-pipes/