# Reading attribute values from HTML

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have HTML stored in a string. The markup contains form `input` fields called *initval* and *endval* which are the `value` attribute values I need. How can I get them from this string markup?

```
<form id="compute">
   <input type="hidden" name="initval" value="tal:00far" />
   <input type="hidden" name="endval" value="utl:80er" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Jere: You can’t say that in general. It depends on the HTML code and what you’re trying to do with it.

Comment: @Jere: That isn't a pro tip, that is often wrong, it is a lack-of-understanding tip.

Comment: Is the form always just like that, or can it be wildly varied, invalid, etc?

Comment: @Gumbo Already having this argument today, wish people would learn the difference between parsing and minor text matching/alterations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358677/regex-selecting-everything-but-img-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that the structure is very reliably like that, try the following:

```
$htmlCode = "...";
$matches = array();

if (preg_match_all('/name="(initval|endval)"\s+value="([^"]+)"/', $htmlCode, $matches)) {
    $formValues = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
} else {
   // error
}
```

This assumes only whitespace between the `name` and `value` attributes, you'll need to make a small change if it differs.  [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) returns an array with the whole regexp match at `[0]`, and then the individual group matches in their corresponding locations `[1]` & `[2]`, the array combine takes one as keys, one as values and puts it together so you have an associative lookup to get your results.

Comment: No it won't, he said it was in that order though, changing it to suit any order is not overly complex.  It's also a bit unsafe not putting it within an input tag, but like I say, this is the bare minimum for a specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question right,
In HTML

```
<form id="compute" action="somefile.php" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="initval" value="tal:00far" />
  <input type="hidden" name="endval" value="utl:80er" />
  <input type="submit" value="Click!">
</form>
```

Upon clicking submit the data is sent the the php script, where it can be read as

```
$initval = $_GET['initval'];
$endval =$_GET['endval'];
```

**EDIT**: It seems I have got the question wrong, Sorry. :-(

Comment: The form isn't a form that's being submitted. It's just markup stored in a string, so I mean getting the values via string manipulation.

Comment: you can always delete your answer if you want to do that to avoid confusing future readers. all these comments will be gone with it also.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using htmldomlibraries for parsing html.